# change order of <li> in JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, html-lists

This is my django generated navigation menu:

```
<nav class="nav-collapse"> 
 <ul>
     <li id="1">1</li>
     <li id="2">2</li>
     <li id="3">3</li>
     <li id="4">4</li>

     <li id="logo"><img/></li> <!-- this <li> is added by me -->

 </ul>
</nav>
```

How can I use javascript or jQuery in order to make it look like this:

```
<nav class="nav-collapse"> 
 <ul>
     <li id="1">1</li>
     <li id="2">2</li>

     <li id="logo"><img/></li>

     <li id="3">3</li>
     <li id="4">4</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvuuxc1w/

```
$( "<li id='logo'><img/></li>").insertBefore( "#3" );
```

Comment: Thank you all! I went for this one :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insertAfter()` to detach the element then insert it where you want it:

```
$("#logo").insertAfter("#2");
```

This effectively will move `#logo` from the bottom to be in-between `#2` and `#3`.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/opwdv10s/3/)

Comment: detach part is redundant, is already going to be detached in order to be inserted http://jsfiddle.net/opwdv10s/2/

Comment: @charlietfl Good call, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
var logoHtml='<li id="logo"><img/></li>';
$(".nav-collapse").find("li").eq(1).append(logoHtml);
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycctjbzn/)

Comment: Wouldn't this add another `<li id="logo">` to the page if one is already there?